# Manhattan Distance and Triangle Inequality

Tags: algorithm, geometry, distance

The question came around in [CSAcademy Programming Contest Round 51](https://csacademy.com/contest/round-51/task/manhattan-distances/) though. The problem statement reads:-
"Given Manhattan distances a,b and c, produce 3 points in 2D space such that the manhattan distances amongst them satisfies the aforementioned values".
**My Approach**
The distances given should satisfy:-

```
(a+b+c)%2==0
```

The reason being:
Sort the distances first such that

```
a<=b<=c
```

Then we have the following

```
|x2-x1|+|y2-y1|=a
|x3-x2|+|y3-y2|=b
|x3-x1|+|y3-y2|=c
```

Now, if 3 points have x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3 coordinates such that:-

```
x1<=x2<=x3
y1<=y2<=y3
```

Then we can safely open modulus to get:-

```
2*(x3-x1)+2*(y3-y1)=a+b+c
```

Thereafter, I fixed (0,0) and (a,0), and derived the 3rd point as:-

```
x3=(a+b-c)/2
y3=(b+c-a)/2
```

However, I couldn't solve in the contest because I didn't take care of the fact that after sorting

```
a+b>=c should hold (Triangle inequality over Manhattan Distance)
```

The code for the same [here](https://ideone.com/QIdpsE).
Thus, my questions are as follows:-

1. How does Manhattan distance satisfies triangle inequality?
2. Does any general distance metric hold the triangle inequality? (Like Manhattan, Levehnstein (edit distance), Hamming distance).
3. Is the Triangle inequality a necessary condition for all distance measures? (That is it should fundamentally hold).

Comment: [This google books link](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ofp4h_oXsZ4C&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=manhattan+distance+triangle&source=bl&ots=XKo_jmbvKM&sig=SxnMDXZlk2QQzW25Gt_jPtmKoTk&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYxavayNrWAhXFBBoKHTrgA3QQ6AEIcTAM#v=onepage&q=manhattan%20distance%20triangle&f=false) shows how triangle inequality is violated.

Comment: You are supposing that `x1<=x2<=x3` and 
`y1<=y2<=y3` but what if it's not possible? When you're calculating x3 and y3 do they always satisfy those inequalities?

Comment: Anyways, the solution perform yield a linear combination of the distances by 2. e.g. (a+b-c)/2 or (b+c-a)/2 etc. For the numerator to be divisble, there can only be even number of odd distances. so that the total combination is divisible by 2. Following are invalid:- 1,6,4 or 3,7,5, because each odd number = 2*k+1.

Comment: You could try ticket price:https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/british-rail-s-shocking-defiance-of-standard-metrics/

Answer (score 2):

I think the meaning is simply that the points you have produced do not satisfy the basic requirements.

I don't believe there is any explicit requirement for the points to satisfy the triangle inequality, this is just an emergent property.

Suppose a=0, b=2, c=4.

Your method will produce points:

```
x1,y1 = 0,0
x2,y2 = 0,0
x3,y3 = -1,3
```

Now distance 1 to 2 is 0, distance 2 to 3 is 4, but distance 1 to 3 is also 4.

The reason for mentioning the triangle inequality is that in this case you can immediately prove that there can be no solutions because of this inequality.

The triangle inequality will hold for distance metrics where the distance is defined as a constrained shortest path.  This is because it is equivalent to saying "going from a to b to c" is always at least as long as "going straight from a to c".

Comment: The distances given are non-zero integers. I shared the problem link (because I couldn't write all the details).

Comment: Fair enough, try with a=2,b=2,c=10 instead.  Measure the distances of the resulting points and you will find that they do not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: The distances you provided don't satisfy triangle inequality, and according to the code it will return -1 or not possible for such input. That is the fundamental question, why triangle inequality holds?